# Annotated method is not intercepted by Around in AspectJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I'm trying to intercept the execution of an annotated method to log the execution time; so I create a new annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}
```

I apply the annotation over the method that I want to trace (the class of the method is not annotated, like @Service or @Component; is this a problem?):

```
@LogExecutionTime
public void execute() throws Exception {
...
}
```

Then I create the class and the @Around method:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PerformanceAnnotation {

@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
public void logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Logger logger = getClassLogger(joinPoint);
    logger.info("Started method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " of class " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    joinPoint.proceed();
    long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    logger.info("Execution time (millis): " + executionTime);
}
}
```

And I add the spring-boot-starter-aop dependency in the pom, and the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy to the main class (the @SpringBootApplication annotated one ).
I expect that when I call the execute() method, the method logExecutionTime() ( the one annotated with @Around) is called first. But it doesn't. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I apply the annotation over the method that I want to trace (the class of the method is not annotated, like `@Service` or `@Component`; is this a problem?):

Yes, it is. Spring cannot apply AOP on classe that he's not aware of. I tried your code and it works if the method annoted with `@LogExecutionTime` is in a class annoted with `@Service` (or `@Component`...).

Comment: You have to annotate tha class as service, and autowire it in the class where you calls the annotated method

Comment: @S-Wing Yes, that's it, then Spring can do it's magic ;)